# awk getline not accepting external variable from a file

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file test.sh from which I am executing the following awk command.

```
awk -f x.awk < result/output.txt  >>difference.txt
```

x.awk

```
while (getline < result/$bld/$DeviceType)
```

the variable DeviceType and bld are available in `test.sh`.

I have declared them as export type.

```
export DeviceType=$line
```

Even then while executing test.sh file, the script stops at following line

```
awk -f x.awk < result/output.txt  >>difference.txt
```

and I am getting

```
awk: x.awk:4: (FILENAME=- FNR=116) fatal: division by zero attempted
 error.
```

Comment: what is result/output.txt ? what data it contains ? First check both data before applying / operation.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with data. Because, if i hard code the file path like   while (getline < result/23/XXX), the output is perfect. Only when i use the variable to find the path,like while (getline < result/$bld/$DeviceType) it shows path not found error.

Answer (score 1):

awk is not shell just like C is not shell. You should not expect to be able to access shell variables within an awk program any more than you can access shell variables within a C program.

To pass the VALUE of shell variables to an awk script, see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for details but essentially:

```
awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" '{ ... use awkvar ...}'
```

is usually the right approach.

Having said that, whatever you're trying to do it looks like the wrong approach. If you are considering using getline, make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first and understand all of the caveats but if you tell us what it is you're trying to do with sample input and expected output we can almost certainly help you come up with a better approach that has nothing to do with getline.

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` script is read by `awk`, not touched by the shell.  Inside an `awk` script, `$bld` means 'the field designated by the number in the variable `bld`' (that's the `awk` variable `bld`).

You can set `awk` variables on the command line (officially with the `-v` option):

```
awk -v bld="$bld" -v dev="$DeviceType" -f x.awk < result/output.txt >> difference.txt
```

Whether that does what you want is still debatable.  Most likely you need `x.awk` to contain something like:

```
BEGIN { file = sprintf("result/%s/%s", bld, dev); }
{ while ((getline < file) > 0) print }
```

Comment: That script will probably go into an infinite loop when it tries to run on a file that's not readable or doesn't exist since getline returns `-1` on [some] errors. If you're considering using getline, make sure to read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and fully understand all of the caveats, appropriate uses and relatively safe syntax.

Comment: @EdMorton: you're correct — I was dealing with other aspects of the problem than the details of the `getline` test — which is only an excuse.

Comment: Make that http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline instead of awk.info.